# Power steering fluid started to leak after changing it

Tags: power-steering, hyundai, elantra

I have a Hyundai Elantra 2002 and changed its power steering fluid with a turkey baster. Four days after changing the power steering fluid and running 1000 miles I noticed that the power steering fluid is leaking. I filled it up up to Max level when I changed it, but after four days it is leveled at Min. So apparently, it is leaking. It was not leaking previously, but now after changing the power steering fluid, it is leaking. Is it normal? What should I do?

Comment: What was the level before you changed it?  What's the source of the loss (have you found any leaks)?  As a side note, I've found that in my Eclipse there's no point in filling it over about halfway between min/max as it will just blow any more than that out.

Comment: it was between min and max before change. The reservoir and the hoses connected to it are fine. But I see some drops by the wheel near passenger side. I cannot say for sure what the source is. Update: I checked the level today in the morning, and it is now below min. So, it is definitely leaking even when the car is not running.

Comment: You can always try adding power steering leak-stop fluid to the system and see if that makes the problem go away. :-)

Comment: yeah, I am doing it, every two or three days. Still no luck, let's see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There use to be a say that you never changed you transmission fluid from whatever to whatever, due to detergents eating up any little bit of soil that might have been holding a leak back. Assuming you used the same fluid type, and the other fluid was filthy enough to have a positive viscosity gain, the new fluid might have found the weakest link. Look for the hose with dirt on it, and trace it. Also, look at you steering rack, as this might be the source of the leak. If available, top the fluid off, and have someone turn the wheel from maximum left turn to max right. Observe all the components, and look for your culprit. Another thing to do is check your hoses for a breach, and if you find one, you might as well replace all hoses to avoid the weakest link failing next.

Comment: Thanks FossilizedCarlos for your comments, Indeed, your right. I have a ´93 Cutlass with a little low level, and after I replenish as low as 5 ml of new ATF oil to the steering oil reservoir, in less than 12 hrs I have a leak (located in the steering oil pressure bulb). Also ATF caused a lot of harm, cause it has a lot of detergents. Never use this oil here.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have a leak. Get under your vehicle and check the PS hoses on the pressure side. There is a hose that has sections of metal pipe joined by rubber Hose. The rubber hose is for flexibility. Most likely it will be a section of metal hose leaking due to corrosion. As for changing your fluid with a Turkey baster, not ideal! Remember there is a lot more fluid in the system than what is visible in the reservoir. I would have removed a hose on the return side of the system and allowed the system to pump itself dry and then reattached the hose and refilled the system. Make sure to have some spare clamps and hose before you do that though or you may be "parked" for a bit as I once was.